# как проверить пустой ли DOM элемент и если он пустой, то скрыть его

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть много контейнеров с списками, которые динамически подгружаются с массива что я получаю с джейсона. Данных может быть много и самого разного, поэтому пробую сделать проверку чтобы не было пустых контейнеров. Сразу же думал использовать ng-if, это казалось более всего подходящим, но вот в чем возникла загвоздка.

```
<div>
  <h1>Birds</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-if="bird.type === 'bird'"
        ng-repeat="bird in creatures">{{bird.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

В массиве много обьектов и нужно их проверять по очереди, поэтому сначала нужно пускать ng-repeat, но в данном случае я его не могу повесить на родительский div т.к. будет повторяться заголовок в каждом обьекте. Я его цепляю на li, но в таком случае я уже на родительском элементе не ng-if="bird.type === 'bird'", тк он еще на тот момент не задан. И выходит проблема в том что если нет списка, то на странице будет только заголовок..
Если бы можно было проверить что список пуст - и скрыть родительский элемент, есть ли такая возможность?
[пример Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/zNbPd6Q2OzX0guk578iw?p=preview)

Comment: если элементов нет значит `creatures.length` будет `== 0`. вот вам и условие для блока отсутствия элеементов

Comment: @Василий Барбашев к сожалению это не так. creatures всегда имеет уйму обьектов, и как в данном примере что на планкр - могут быть и собаки и коты и птицы, но вот рыбы, которую мы ожидаем, может и не быть. но чтобы добраться до рыбы - нужно сделать ng-repeat, тк мы не знаем кого именно из существ у нас может не быть

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае нужна фильтрация массива. Она может быть осуществлена непосредственно во view, либо внутри контроллера.

Например:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.creatures = [{
      name: 'Cho-cho',
      type: 'bird'
    }, {
      name: 'Floo-floo',
      type: 'dog'
    }, {
      name: 'Pou-pou',
      type: 'bird'
    }, {
      name: 'Oop-flup',
      type: 'bird'
    }, {
      name: 'Chio-mio',
      type: 'cat'
    }, {
      name: 'Floo-floo',
      type: 'dog'
    }, {
      name: 'Loo-Li',
      type: 'dog'
    }, {
      name: 'Pops-Mops',
      type: 'bird'
    }, {
      name: 'Boo-Moo',
      type: 'dog'
    }, {
      name: 'Iop-Pio',
      type: 'dog'
    }, {
      name: 'Floop-cho',
      type: 'bird'
    }, {
      name: 'Bop-Bou',
      type: 'cat'
    }

  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="birds=(creatures|filter:{type:'bird'});
              dogs=(creatures|filter:{type:'dog'});
              cats=(creatures|filter:{type:'cat'});
              fishes=(creatures|filter:{type:'fish'})">
  <div ng-if="birds.length>0">
    <h1>Birds</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="bird in birds">{{bird.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="dogs.length>0">
    <h1>Dogs</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="dog in dogs">{{dog.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="cats.length>0">
    <h1>Cats</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="cat in cats">{{cat.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="fishes.length>0">
    <h1>Fishes</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="fish in fishes">{{fish.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо) это я этот вопрос на stackoverflow.com задал) если честно то в мелких маштабах их ответы помогают, но вот когда нужно искать тип в some.rest[0].ino.topi[1].type, это выходит проблематичнее)

Comment: @YoroDiallo, не совсем понял начало комментария. Конец не понял совсем :-) единственное решение задачи: предварительно обработать исходный набор данных. Где и каким образом обрабатывать значения не имеет.

Comment: я в смысле что этот вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794479/hide-parent-element-in-dom-when-children-are-empty/38794916#38794916 я задал, поэтому этот коммент уже видел)) но все равно спасибо)

Comment: @YoroDiallo, но я этот вопрос не видел :)